# Viewing the review comments from pull request within visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

Is there any option to work with the review comments given for a pull request within Visual Studio?  I can view the review comments from Visual Studio online, but it is less productive, I prefer to see the review comments inline within Visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any option to do this. A similar feature request has been submitted in Visual Studio User Voice and you can vote it here: [Be able to review Pull Requests in the Team Explorer window](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/9757926-be-able-to-review-pull-requests-in-the-team-explor).